# Extract list of unique concatenated items from a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of values as shown in the code below. I want to create a list of strings comprising one list item per unique Name with all the unique Hashes (per computer) appended, as follows:

```
C1:H1 
C2:H1,H2
```

The below code works, but I'd like to do it the more Python/better way and I figure it could probably be done with one or two comprehension lines rather than this rambling mess, but I can't figure out how. I first used a nested comprehension adding to a set but then it fell apart after that...

```
def test_data():
    return [
        {
            "Name": "C1",
            "Hash": "H1",
        },
        {
            "Name": "C1",
            "Hash": "H1",
        },
        {
            "Name": "C2",
            "Hash": "H1",
        },
        {
            "Name": "C2",
            "Hash": "H1",
        },
        {
            "Name": "C2",
            "Hash": "H2",
        }
    ]

payload = test_data()

items = {}
#create dictionary of unique computers
for item in payload:
    name = item["Name"]
    hash = item["Hash"]
    if name not in items:
        items[name] = []
    if hash not in items[name]:
        items[name].append(hash)

final_list = []
#create one line list from dictionary
for key in items:
    entry = key
    hashes = ",".join(items[entry])
    entry += ":" + hashes
    final_list.append(entry)

print("\n".join(final_list))
# C1:H1
# C2:H1,H2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace your code with the following list comprehensions (although what you have is just fine):

```
items = {d["Name"]: set(p["Hash"] for p in payload if p["Name"]==d["Name"]) for d in payload}

final_list = [f"{k}: {','.join(v)}" for k,v in items.items()]

>>> print("\n".join(final_list))
C1: H1
C2: H2,H1
```

Comment: Thanks. My brain just melted reading it, but it was just what I was after.

Comment: Haha, your code is more readable. You might consider sticking to it at least to get the `items` dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [
    {"Name": "C1", "Hash": "H1"},
    {"Name": "C1", "Hash": "H1"},
    {"Name": "C2", "Hash": "H1"},
    {"Name": "C2", "Hash": "H1"},
    {"Name": "C2", "Hash": "H2"},
]

keys = set(d["Name"] for d in data)
print(keys)
# {'C2', 'C1'}

items = {k: set(d["Hash"] for d in data if d["Name"] == k) for k in keys}
print(items)
# {'C2': {'H1', 'H2'}, 'C1': {'H1'}}
```

Then you can do what you want with `items`

And if you really like one-liners:

```
items = {
    d1["Name"]: set(d2["Hash"] for d2 in data if d2["Name"] == d1["Name"])
    for d1 in data
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was after a list returned not a dictionary, but your answer is very useful and I've kept it for later. No need to spend more time as another answer does the list.